# better method for initializing array

Tags: c++, arrays

Looks a newbie question, but this function is called many times, to be honest thousands of time per-second, so an optimization is CRUCIAL in here. What would be the best method?

```
struct CHOLDELEM
{
    DWORD dwColor[3], dwItemId[3];
    int nPos[3], nLength[3];
    CItemElem* pItem[3];
    CHOLDELEM()
    {
        for( int i=0; i<=3; i++ )
        {
            dwColor[i] = dwItemId[i] = 0;
            nPos[i] = nLength[i] = 0;
            pItem[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
};
```

or with `memset`s?

`memset( dwColor, 0, sizeof( dwColor ) );`

or another method.

Comment: ooks a newbie question, but this function is called many times, to be honest thousands of time per-second, so an optimization is CRUCIAL in here. What would be the best method? -- I strongly doubt this.  Being called often != should optimize - please profile to demonstrate that this strip of code is actually slowing your program down.

Comment: The only thing that can tell you the answer for sure is your profiler.

Comment: Anything wrong with `memset`?

Comment: Virtually any optimizing compiler is going to plop down the contents of the for loop three times instead of setting up an actual loop in machine code. However, `memset` will always have the fastest implementation.

Comment: You could speed it up slightly by not writing beyond the end of each array.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I'm sorry I didn't get it. What do you mean?

Comment: `DWORD dwColor[3];` declares an array with 3 valid indexes, namely 0, 1 and 2. There is no index 3. Trying to access `dwColor[3]` is forbidden by the language; it yields undefined behavior (read: anything could happen). Thus, your loop condition should be `i < 3`, not `i <= 3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you are interested in zero initialization only, you can simply do

```
CHOLDELEM() : dwColor(), dwItemId(), nPos(), nLength(), pItem()
  {}
```

(no C++11 necessary).

However, you might want to take a look at the code your compiler generates for it. If it is not optimal somehow, then a better idea might be to keep your struct a POD (no constructor) and initialize it "from outside" when you declare objects of that type

```
CHOLDELEM c = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler can handle C++11 initializers, then you can set the array values in the constructor initializer list:

```
CHOLDELEM() :
    dwColor{0}, dwItemId{0}, nPos{0}, nLength{0}, pItem{nullptr}
    { }
```

Then the compiler will generate (pretty optimal) code to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use the `memset` approach, but I would definitely want to make sure that it doesn't break when more complex data members are added to `CHOLDELEM`:

```
#include <type_traits>

// ...

    CHOLDELEM()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<CHOLDELEM>::value,
                      "It is no longer safe to use memset!");
        memset(this, 0, sizeof *this);
    }
```

By the way, `CHOLDELEM` is a terrible name. Why don't you rename it to `ElementHolder` or something?

Comment: all structs god knows why start with a C and caps lock on this source, I'm just following...

Comment: What do you mean "all structs"? All structs your teacher uses?